# Nullable DateTime to String

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to convert Nullable DataTime to string.

```
DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now;
string strdatetime = datetime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Above coding working fine, non nullable DateTime.

```
DateTime? datetime = DateTime.Now;
string strdatetime = datetime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

This one showing error **`No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments`**.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this one,

```
 string strdatetime = datetime.HasValue ? datetime.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : string.Empty;
```